# Mapbox Android SDK 4.0.0+ - how to set zoom & center map on given location?

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox Android SDK v4.0.0 in an Android app that at some point needs to "freeze" a MapView at a given position and a given zoom level.

It seems to me that there are no methods in the API to:

1. Set a specific zoom level for a map,
2. Center a map on a given location.

How to get this done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems the API has changed between versions 3.2.0 and 4.0.0. Currently, to achieve the above goal, you need to use a `CameraPosition` and inject it into your `mapboxMap`:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        mapboxMap.setCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(yourLatLng)
                .zoom(yourZoom)
                .build());
    }
});
```

Works like a charm.